# grep double quote in cron

Tags: cron, grep

i run this command on the terminal

```
$ my_json_generator.rb | grep \"mtype\":164 | my_json_consumer.rb
```

json_generator creates json objects.  1 per line.

```
{"foo":7, "mtype":164, "bar":[1,2,3]}
```

I only need lines that contain mtype of 164 and for performance reasons ( and others outside the scope of this question ) i would like to avoid parsing the other json lines into objects.  I recognize I could do this in code but need to avoid it.

So, the above command works on the terminal, but not in cron.  Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a `$PATH` problem.

Try putting the full `PATH` of the executables, or add at the beginning of your `crontab` :

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
MAIL=me@domain.tld

* * * * * my_json_generator.rb | grep \"mtype\":164 | my_json_consumer.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean it doesn't work? Try removing the backslash from the Crontab entry. It might be double escaped.